# Racket find shared elements between lists

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to create a specific response for a given list if it has shared elements with another list. As in if I have a list that is (My name is John) and I have another list of (John Adam Jacob) I would want the first list to be able to see that John is in the second list, and be able to print something along the lines of (this is a known name) or something similiar.

The code I have thought of uses map, and member.

```
(define (specific-reply user-list)
     (cond (member (map (lambda (user-list)) '(John Adam Jacob)))
            (write (this is a known name))
      (else 
            (write (this is not a known name)))))
```

I'm extremely knew to both racket and scheme however and I haven't really gotten it to compile yet so I think I'm largely off.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to complicate the problem if your task is to just find if **a** is a member of `(a b c)`,

Here's a piece of *Scheme* code that can tell if `a` is a member of `lat`.
It's just a simple recursive function that compares each element of lat with a for a match.

```
(define member?
    (lambda (a lat)
        (cond
            ((null? lat) #f)
            ((eq? a lat) #t)
            (else
                 (member? a (cdr lat))))))
```

If you want to take this further and find the intersection of two lists, we can do something like this!

```
(define intersect
    (lambda (set1 set2)
            (letrec
              ((I (lambda (set)
                      (cond
                           ((null? set) (quote ()))
                           ((member? (car set) set2)
                            (cons (car set)
                                  (I (cdr set))))
                           (else (I (cdr set)))))))
            (I set1))))
```

You can use this code as such. Tested from **guile** compiler

```
(begin
      (display (intersect `(1 2 3) `(1 3 4 5 2)))
      (newline))

>> (1 2)
```

**EDIT**

I recommend you read [The Little Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262560992) and the [The Seasoned Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/026256100X) to get more familiar with these kind of concepts

Answer (score 1):

One can also use built-in functions `filter` and `member` to find intersection of 2 lists:

```
(define (intersection l1 l2)
  (remove-duplicates
   (filter (λ (x) (member x l1))  
           l2)))
```

Above checks each item of l2 to keep it only if it is a member of l1 also.

One can also use `for/list` to check each element and return a list of common items:

```
(define (intersect l1 l2)
  (remove-duplicates
   (for/list ((i l1)
              #:when (member i l2))
     i)))
```

Both above function remove duplicates. Just avoiding use of `remove-duplicates` may result in different result if simply the order of l1 and l2 is interchaged. If one wants that the repeated elements to come repeatedly in outcome list, one can use following function in which common items are removed before proceeding:

```
(define (intersection2 l1 l2)
  (let loop ((l1 l1)
             (l2 l2)
             (ol '()))
    (cond
      [(empty? l1) (reverse ol)]
      [(member (first l1) l2)        ; first item of l1 is common
       (loop (rest l1)               ; loop with rest of l1
             (remove (first l1) l2)  ; remove common item from l2
             (cons (first l1) ol))]  ; add common item to outlist
      [else
       (loop (rest l1)
             l2
             ol)])))
```

Testing:

```
(intersection2 '(2 4 2 7 2 10) '(10 2 9 2 0 11))
```

Output:

```
'(2 2 10)
```

Comment: `member` is not a higher-order function (at least not when used without its optional 3rd argument).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`set`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html?q=set#%28tech._set%29) in racket:

```
(define (list-intersect-2 lst1 lst2)
  (set->list
   (set-intersect (list->set lst1)
                  (list->set lst2))))
```

For a solution that takes one or more lists:

```
(define (list-intersect lst1 . lstn)
  (set->list
   (foldl set-intersect
          (list->set lst1)
          (map list->set lstn))))


(list-intersect '(1 2 3) '(2 3 4) '(3 4 8))
; ==> (3)
```